# Java add JLayeredPane in a table cell?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to add a `JLayeredPane()` inside a `JTable`?

Ive tried:

```
     JLayeredPane agentPicturePane = new JLayeredPane();
     String agentPicture = "http://www.domain.com/uploads/thumb_23.jpg";

     try {
         final BufferedImage image = resize(new URL(agentPicture), new Dimension(60, 60));
         jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(image));
     } catch (Exception ex) {

     }

     jLabel6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/imageBg.png")));

     jLabel1.setBounds(13, 13, 60, 60);
     jLabel6.setBounds(0, 0, 86, 86);
     agentPicturePane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(86, 86));
     agentPicturePane.add(jLabel6, new Integer(50));
     agentPicturePane.add(jLabel1, new Integer(100));

     visitorModel.addRow(new Object[] {
         agentPicturePane, visitorName, visitorClose
     });
```

Using model:

```
        visitorModel = new DefaultTableModel(productss, colNamee) { 
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
               //all cells false
               return false;
            }     
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            //  return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
                return (column == 0 || column == 2) ? Icon.class : Object.class;
            }
        };
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: The short answer is why?  The long answer is why?  You should not be mixing data with view responsibilities.  That is, `JLayeredPane` (in your example) does not belong in the model, it should form part of the view portion of the Model-View-Control paradigm.  Take a look at [Using Custom Reneders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) to see how you can provide custom views for table cells...

Comment: I want to display the layered images in a selectable list form

Comment: You are confusing model with rendering. A JTable cell does not hold components but rather data that is used by the renderer to render images of components. Re-read the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confusing your areas of responsibility.  The `TableModel` is only suppose to carry data.  It's up to the view to decide how that data is to be rendered.

If you need to provide some kind of custom rendering, then you need to supply your `TableCellRenderer`

This example uses compound `JLabel`s and a `EmptyBorder` to provide the overlay functionality.

So using the two images below...

[image][image]

I was able to produce...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class LayeredCellRenderer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayeredCellRenderer();
    }

    public LayeredCellRenderer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(new File("Photo01.jpg"));

                    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                            new Object[][]{{pic, "Sophia", ""}},
                            new Object[]{"Picture", "Name", "Close"});

                    JTable table = new JTable(model);
                    table.setRowHeight(86);
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new SecutiryBadgeTableCellRenderer());

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class SecutiryBadgeTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        protected static BufferedImage background;
        private JLabel subImage;

        public SecutiryBadgeTableCellRenderer() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("Background.jpg"));
                setIcon(new ImageIcon(background));
                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                subImage = new JLabel();
                subImage.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                subImage.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
                subImage.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(30, 10, 0, 0));
                add(subImage);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, null, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (value instanceof Image) {
                Image img = (Image) value;
                subImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon((Image) value));
                subImage.setSize(subImage.getPreferredSize());
            } else {
                subImage.setIcon(null);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

For more details see [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: AWESOME! This is exactly what i wanted to accomplish thank you a ton!