# how to set two background colors in JTable cell in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know how to set background color in Jtable cell in java Swing, but i don't know how to set two background colors in one cell. Below is the example img:

[image]

I need a help to make it (Using java Swing only), Thanks in advance !

Comment: Create a custom renderer. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Use a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). In your case you might use a panel with two labels. You can set the text and background of each label,

Comment: It might make more sense to break the `Color` column into two columns (`Color 1` & `Color 2`).

Comment: This *may* help you as well - [Multiple objects in a single JTable cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464899/multiple-object-in-a-single-jtable-cell).

Answer (score 0):

@ camickr   Thanks camickr!  i done it  as your way,  i post below code that using my
Swing application:

```
 JPanel panel;
 JLabel jl1= new JLabel("1");
 JLabel jl2= new JLabel("1");

 class PanelRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
public PanelRenderer() {
setOpaque( true );
init();
}

private void init() {
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
jl1.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
jl1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
jl1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
jl1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
jl1.setOpaque(true);
add(jl1);

jl2.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
jl2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
jl2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
jl2.setBackground(new Color(85, 134, 235));
jl2.setOpaque(true);
add(jl2);


}


@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table, Object value, boolean 
isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column ) {
if ( isSelected )
{
 .....
} else
{
....
}
return this;
}


}


class PanelEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {


public PanelEditor( JTextField txt ) {
super( txt );
   ....

}


@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent( JTable table, Object value, boolean 
isSelected, int row, int column ) {
  .... 
return panel;
}
} 

.....
// load data from database with the renderer
 TableCellRenderer colorRenderer = new  PanelRenderer();
my_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(colorRenderer);
```

[image]